# Why does brew upgrade phantomjs tell me to update my xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, phantomjs, homebrew

I have an older version of phantomjs:

```
 phantomjs -v
 2.0.0
```

I update the list:

```
$ brew update
Already up-to-date.
```

Then I try to upgrade phantomjs to latest version 2.1.1:

```
$ brew upgrade phantomjs
Error: Your Xcode (8.3.3) is too outdated.
```

And the error:

> Error: Your Xcode (8.3.3) is too outdated. Please update to Xcode 9.4
>   (or delete it). Xcode can be updated from the App Store.

Why do I need to update Xcode in order to upgrade `phantomjs` to version 2.1.1?

Answer (score 1):

Because it needs to compile the C and C++ in phantomjs. Homebrew requires a recent version of Xcode, along with recent macOS SDKs that come with Xcode, to do that.